# Invertible matrix with nonnegative entries

Tags: matrices, inverse, nonnegative-matrices

> Let $A \in \text{GL}(n,\mathbb R)$ with all nonnegative entries such that $A^{-1}$ also has all nonnegative entries.
>
> How many nonzero entries does $A$ have, what are their locations, and what are the entries of $A^{-1}$ in terms of the nonnegative entries of $A$?

My attempt:

Diagonal matrices $D$ with all positive diagonal elements are examples of matrices so characterized. Such matrices have $n^2-n$ zero entries and $n$ non-zero entries and the non-zero elements of $D^{-1}$ are diagonal entries, each the reciprocal of the corresponding location on the diagonal of $D$.

For $A$ not diagonal, I tried equating cofactors of $A$ with cofactors of $A^{-1}$ and seeing which entries are equal to their negative. I couldn't get any obvious way to equate them, though.

Edit: I'd prefer a proof that doesn't rely on graph theory, a subject in which I'm unfamiliar. Presumably this is solvable just with matrix algebra or determinants.

Comment: I'd prefer an answer that doesn't appeal to graph theory because I'm unfamiliar with it, and I'd like to know if my cofactor idea is salvageable

Comment: @Dietrich I asked a question on one of the answers there, maybe if that's clarified I can close this question

Comment: There is an elementary answer at the same question.

Comment: @kevin can you please help me with my question on that answer?